# Gatsby JS - gatsby-plugin-scroll-reveal not activating

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm currently testing out the plugin - [gatsby-plugin-scroll-reveal](https://github.com/solublestudio/gatsby-plugin-scroll-reveal#readme)
I've added it to my `gatsby-config.js` like so:

```
plugins: [
        ...

        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-scroll-reveal`,
            options: {
                threshold: 0.1, // Percentage of an element's area that needs to be visible to launch animation
                once: true, // Defines if animation needs to be launched once
                disable: false, // Flag for disabling animations

                // Advanced Options
                selector: "[data-sal]", // Selector of the elements to be animated
                animateClassName: "sal-animate", // Class name which triggers animation
                disabledClassName: "sal-disabled", // Class name which defines the disabled state
                rootMargin: "0% 50%", // Corresponds to root's bounding box margin
                enterEventName: "sal:in", // Enter event name
                exitEventName: "sal:out", // Exit event name
            },
        }
       ...
    ],
```

Then in my `index.js` (main page), I have:

```
<div data-sal={"slide-up"} data-sal-delay={"100"} data-sal-easing={"ease"}>
    <video
        width={"100%"}
        height={"661px"}
        autoPlay
        muted
        loop
        playsInline
        preload={"auto"}
        type={"video/webm"}
    >
        <source src={HomeHeroVideo} media={"(min-width: 768px)"} />
    </video>
</div>
```

When I scroll to the element, it's just a big space where the div for the video should have been. It is as if the animation is not being activated.. I inspected the element and it seems like this is causing it to be hidden:

```
[data-sal|=slide] {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity,-webkit-transform;
    transition-property: opacity,-webkit-transform;
    transition-property: opacity,transform;
    transition-property: opacity,transform,-webkit-transform;
```

}

Did I miss a step to activate it on the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, ditch the plugin. You're not wrong for looking for an easy solution, but for what you're doing there's nothing Gatsby specific and this plugin is tying you to [sal.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sal.js), which is built in the Unobtrusive JavaScript style (about as opposite to React as it gets).

You're going to be better served by a React-oriented solution, of which there are many. My favorite is to just use an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) wrapper ([like this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer)) to detect this on a per-component basis and set the relevant styes.

Add `react-intersection-observer` to your dependencies, then you can do this:

```
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer"

const AutoPlayingVideo = ({ threshold = 0.15, ...playerProps }) => {
  const [ref, inView] = useInView({ threshold })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      ref.current?.play()
    } else {
      ref.current?.pause()
    }
  }, [ref, inView])

  return (
    <video
      style={{
        transition: "opacity 300ms, transform 300ms",
        opacity: inView ? 1 : 0,
        transform: `translateY(${inView ? 0 : 100}px)`,
      }}
      ref={ref}
      autoPlay
      playsInline
      muted
      loop
      {...playerProps}
    />
  )
}
```

In less code you get a reusable video component with an animated entry that automatically plays while in view and pauses once out of view! Use it like this:

```
<AutoPlayingVideo
  width="100%"
  height="661"
  preload="auto"
  type="video/webm"
>
  <source src={HomeHeroVideo} media={"(min-width: 768px)"} />
</video>
```

Also, if you find yourself using this a lot, it's easy to extract the common behavior to a component of its own for you to reuse:

```
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer"

const AnimateIn = ({ threshold = 0.15, triggerOnce = false, distance = 100, ...remainingProps }) => {
  const [ref, inView] = useInView({ threshold, triggerOnce })

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        // adjust these as desired
        transition: "opacity 300ms, transform 300ms",
        opacity: inView ? 1 : 0,
        transform: `translateY(${inView ? 0 : distance}px)`,
      }}
      {...remainingProps}
    />
  )
}

// In use:
<AnimateIn distance={30} triggerOnce={true}>
  <h1>Hi Mom!</h1>
</AnimateIn>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Essentially, this is what I want to achieve when it's in view (I've created a simple fiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/ynL4r3zd/
I've also created a sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-driscoll-mwz36?file=/src/AnimateIn.js) based on your suggestion but finding it a bit hard to implement above using your method. What's the best way to achieve that, and have keyframes inline/activated when it's in view?

Comment: @drifterOcean19 If you're using `animation` just wait until the element is `inView` to set the `animation` property on the element's styles. E.g. `style={{ animation: inView ? "your-animation" : "none" }}`